# Any guidelines for using CSS and HTML for developing webapps?

Tags: html, android, css

Is there any official guide for developing Android apps using HTML and CSS like the ones iPhone has which specifies the guidelines for height/width etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android mobile browser isn't conceptually different from any other mobile browser.

So follow the general W3C guidelines for developing mobile web apps:

http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/

Answer (score 2):

Elastic layouts are probably recommended:
http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Android phones vary in resolution so there aren't really any specific guidelines for height/width.  Instead express them as percentages.